# How to change the padding in popup menu?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, widget, material-design

How can i remove the padding in `PopupMenuButton` ? I tried using `padding` property but it the padding for icons.

but found something in `popup_menu.dart`

```
const double _kMenuHorizontalPadding = 16.0;
const double _kMenuDividerHeight = 16.0;
const double _kMenuMaxWidth = 5.0 * _kMenuWidthStep;
const double _kMenuMinWidth = 2.0 * _kMenuWidthStep;
const double _kMenuVerticalPadding = 8.0;
```

Managed to remove horizontal padding, but I don't know how to remove the vertical padding in the popup menu.

Here is the code that i used to remove the horizontal padding.

```
class AppPopUpMenuState extends PopupMenuItemState<int, AppPopUpButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final PopupMenuThemeData popupMenuTheme = PopupMenuTheme.of(context);
    TextStyle style = widget.textStyle ??
        popupMenuTheme.textStyle ??
        theme.textTheme.subtitle1;

    if (!widget.enabled) style = style.copyWith(color: theme.disabledColor);

    Widget item = AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
      style: style,
      duration: kThemeChangeDuration,
      child: Container(
        color: widget.color,
        width: widget.width,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
 //   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _kMenuHorizontalPadding), //padding in library
        padding: widget.padding,  // code that changed
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: widget.height),
        child: buildChild(),
      ),
    );

    if (!widget.enabled) {
      final bool isDark = theme.brightness == Brightness.dark;
      item = IconTheme.merge(
        data: IconThemeData(opacity: isDark ? 0.5 : 0.38),
        child: item,
      );
    }

    return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.enabled ? handleTap : null,
      canRequestFocus: widget.enabled,
      child: item,
    );
  }
}
```

Code in `PopupMenu` Library for building menu

```
class _PopupMenu<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PopupMenu({
    Key key,
    this.route,
    this.semanticLabel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final _PopupMenuRoute<T> route;
  final String semanticLabel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double unit = 1.0 / (route.items.length + 1.5); // 1.0 for the width and 0.5 for the last item's fade.
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    final PopupMenuThemeData popupMenuTheme = PopupMenuTheme.of(context);

    for (int i = 0; i < route.items.length; i += 1) {
      final double start = (i + 1) * unit;
      final double end = (start + 1.5 * unit).clamp(0.0, 1.0) as double;
      final CurvedAnimation opacity = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: route.animation,
        curve: Interval(start, end),
      );
      Widget item = route.items[i];
      if (route.initialValue != null && route.items[i].represents(route.initialValue)) {
        item = Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
          child: item,
        );
      }
      children.add(
        _MenuItem(
          onLayout: (Size size) {
            route.itemSizes[i] = size;
          },
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: item,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    final CurveTween opacity = CurveTween(curve: const Interval(0.0, 1.0 / 3.0));
    final CurveTween width = CurveTween(curve: Interval(0.0, unit));
    final CurveTween height = CurveTween(curve: Interval(0.0, unit * route.items.length));

    final Widget child = ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: _kMenuMinWidth,
        maxWidth: _kMenuMaxWidth,
      ),
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        stepWidth: _kMenuWidthStep,
        child: Semantics(
          scopesRoute: true,
          namesRoute: true,
          explicitChildNodes: true,
          label: semanticLabel,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: _kMenuVerticalPadding
            ),
            child: ListBody(children: children),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: route.animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: opacity.evaluate(route.animation),
          child: Material(
            shape: route.shape ?? popupMenuTheme.shape,
            color: route.color ?? popupMenuTheme.color,
            type: MaterialType.card,
            elevation: route.elevation ?? popupMenuTheme.elevation ?? 8.0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
              widthFactor: width.evaluate(route.animation),
              heightFactor: height.evaluate(route.animation),
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
 constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: widget.height),
```

this code is setting minimum height for your widget

Comment: removed that still not work, there is a vertical padding in the menu. `const double _kMenuVerticalPadding = 8.0;` this is used there

Comment: cant see that variable in your code, only declaration is present.

Comment: which is declared in the Popupmenu library.

Comment: I meant where it is used? post that code too. only declaration you are showing

Comment: code in the material library updated in the question